# How to read data from text file and assign it to variables? (C++)

Tags: c++

So let's say I have this text file called "items.txt" which contains

```
0|Item Name|Item Desc 1
1|Item Name 1|Item Desc 1
```

Every item in the .txt file has an ID at the beggining of the line, a name and a description. How can I make a program that, for example, prints all the info for item with ID 1 (name, description)?

Comment: The easy approach is to "read a line" (std::getline() does this), and then "parse a string" or "split a string" (std::isstream does this - the string here is each line). When you do this search, you're using the pipe `|` as your "delimiter". Using those search terms you should find what you seek, adventurer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I also missed what you want to DO with this information. It sounds like you want to store each `Item` in a `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, Item>`. Then anything in your program that references this item only uses the ID of the item to refer to it. Any time you need stats about the item or to display the item description, you retrieve the item from the `std::unordered_map` using its `id`. An adventurer's inventory wouldn't hold a series of `Item`s, it only needs to hold a series of `id`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a sepparator to know where the `Name` end and where `Desc` starts. Let's say it is the `|` you used in your example. Also, for simplicity, we assume that you have a number `N` at the begginning of the file so that you know how many items are stored inside it. So we try to read something like this:

In file `items.txt`:

```
2
123|Sword|A basic sword.
124|Bow|A basic bow.
```

You did not state how you intend to store the data of each `Item`, so i will create an `Item` `struct`:

```
struct Item
{
    unsigned int nID;
    char Name[64];
    char Desc[128];
}
```

And now a function that will read Items from a file.

```
Item* ReadItems(std::ifstream& fin, unsigned long& nItemCount)
{
    fin >> nItemCount;
    Item* pItems = new Item[nItemCount];

    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < nItemCount; i++)
    {
        fin >> pItems[i].nID;

        char NameAndDesc[195];
        fin.getline(NameAndDesc, 195);

        char* p = strtok(NameAndDesc, "|");
        strcpy(pItems[i].Name, p);

        p = strtok(NULL, "|");
        strcpy(pItems[i].Desc, p);
    }

    return pItems;
}
```

In your main, you also need to declare the file, handle error checking and free the `Items` array used to store your items:

```
int main()
{
    Item* Items;
    unsigned long nItemCount;

    std::ifstream fin("items.txt");
    if (!fin.good())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid file given.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    try{Items = ReadItems(fin, nItemCount);}
    catch(std::bad_alloc& except)
        {std::cout << except.what(); return -1;}


    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < nItemCount; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Item with ID = " << Items[i].nID << " has the name '" << Items[i].Name << "'.\n";
        std::cout << "Description: " << Items[i].Desc << "\n\n";
    }
    std::cout << "-----------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Total items read: " << nItemCount << "\n";

    delete [] Items;

    return 0;
}
```

Now you have all the items you need in an array. You can do whatever check and modifications you want to them.

---

To specifically answer the question, you just have to loop through all the items and then check the ID.

```
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < nItemCount; i++)
    if (Items[i].nID == 1)
        std::cout << "Found an item with id=1 with name: " << Items[i].Name << "\n";
```

---

Edit: If you want to use the `class` keyword instead, this is how you define the `Item` class:

```
class Item
{
    public:
        unsigned int nID;
        char Name[64];
        char Desc[128];
}
```

If you replace the declaration in the code i provided of `struct Item` with this one, nothing will change at all.

---

*Note*: Sorry i am not familiar with C++ string handling, so i made it using the C library `<string.h>`.

*Note*: If you intend to make an `Item` store a lot more information, like `Damage`, `Attributes` etc, you may want to read and write the items in binary, so that way it is easier and more compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! One little problem though. As I asked in my question, how can I print information for a certain item? (print item by id)

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` and `std::getline(input, text_variable, separator_character)`.

Comment: @Wenor i edited my post to answer the question exactly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews as i mentioned in the answer, i never actually used `std::string` so i will not edit my answer in that sense. I will however change the `fin.getline()` call to also include the separator character you mentioned when i can.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that instead of Struct i used Class. Is there a way I could possibly move the try{} and for() loop from int main() to the Item class?

Comment: If you use c++, there is no difference between `class` and `struct`. The only thing to keep in mind is that a class has all members private by default, and a struct has all of them public. Ill edit the post with the definition of `class Item` and aside from that nothing will change.

Comment: Both `struct` and `class` define classes.

Comment: @Wenor sorry i didnt read your question in the comment until the end. If you want to move the reading of an item into the `Item` constructor you have to redesign your code somehow. If you also want some help there, edit your question and explain how you want it to behave etc.

Comment: I want to add this code: https://prnt.sc/rpyf6k in the Item class but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Wenor Yes it is obvious it wont work, because that code is design to allocate all Items and then read them all. I came up with one solution and that is to make a new class called `ItemArray`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/QP2iYjT9) is how i made it and how i used it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but is there any way I can combine the Item and ItemArray classes into one?

Comment: @Wenor If you want to encapsulate all code into classes, i'm afraid i have no idea how you can do that. If you want to have one single class `Item` you need to do as i did in the answer here. I don't say it is not possible, i say that i have no idea how would the code look like without the `ItemArray` class...